# How to close any window in Awesome WM?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, awesome, window-management

Desktop application developers are free to choose which keyboard shortcuts they want to support. On Windows the convention is pretty strong:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> closes most applications
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> closes most major sub-windows
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> dismisses most dialogue boxes.

On Linux there hasn't been quite so much convergence, but the following are common:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> closes most applications
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> closes most major sub-windows
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> dismisses most dialogue boxes.

Unfortunately many applications have chosen to go their own way, either by using the Windows convention or by just doing their own thing:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> closes Chromium
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> closes GNOME Shell
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> closes IDEA

To close sub-windows and dialogue boxes all bets are off. I've seen all of these in use:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>

Some applications don't even have shortcuts for closing some windows (or at least none that I have been able to find).

**Window managers have the power to override any of these**, and can therefore be very helpful for keyboard users. Awesome WM is very keyboard-friendly, but **are there global shortcuts to close *any* window and/or application in Awesome WM**, and if not, how do I set them up?

Comment: What's wrong with the little X on the title bar?  That should be SIGTERM, meaning it will be no worse than any other external method; applications should catch this and shutdown just as they would via "quit" or whatever.  In short: just close the main window and that should close the application.

Comment: @goldilocks That doesn't work in many WMs (like Awesome), and it's less efficient for someone used to keyboard navigation.

Comment: Doesn't sound very "awesome" to me, lol.  I would strongly refute the assertion that "it doesn't work in many WMs" -- it certainly does work in virtually all of them, or they are plain and simple not serving their intended purpose.  The most basic and fundamental thing: *you provide a window with a titlebar and a close button*.  I agree point and click is less efficient than the keyboard, but que sera -- you are using a GUI -- and any *decent* WM will provide you with keybinding options to do stuff like this. Ie, you need to figure out how to create your own shortcuts.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't generally allow list questions, they're not a good fit for the way the site works (it's expected that you have a particular problem, somebody posts a solution and you accept it). If you find yourself saying "One ______ per answer", that's usually a bad sign

Comment: @goldilocks: I think you misunderstand the purpose of awesome and [tilling window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager) in general. You *should* use them without touching the mouse at all.  Most of them will not decorate windows at all which is a good thing(TM).

Comment: @Sardathrion Sorry for being hyperbolic; I'm aware of tiling WM's, and I prefer the keyboard to the mouse too. My point was that controlling windows is the domain of the window manager and not anything else; the question *as it originally appeared* revolved around the OP saying that since his WM (apparently) did not provide a means of doing basic things, then the "blame" for this lay with individual applications, or the OS -- wrong. If your WM lacks a feature you want or need, consider another WM, don't rail to the skies about how it's everything else which is flawed.

Comment: @goldilocks: Sorry, I did not mean to cause offence and I can see how my comment could be view as such.

Comment: @l0b0 You edited this and it got reopened months ago; I don't know why you're randomly replying to that ancient comment. I still don't understand what the issue is, honestly; Mod4+Shift+c kills the current X client (window), which is the same thing that happens on Windows. If you have a Windows program with multiple windows, Alt+F4 will close one of them, not the entire program. There is no Windows hotkey that closes an application, although Ctrl+q is fairly common, and I don't think there is one in Awesome. It might be possible to bind one, but I don't know Awesome well enough

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Sorry, I replied because I generally assume out-of-date comments are deleted by their authors. Regarding Windows, if the main application window is focused Alt-F4 closes the application. I don't know of a single counterexample.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [`man awesome`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/manpages/awesome.1.html) there doesn't seem to be a default key binding to close all windows of an application. It might be possible to manually add such a binding.

There is, however, a default key binding to **close the one focused window*: <kbd>Mod4</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>**. This will leave other windows (if any) of the application intact. It does *not* work for sub-windows ("logical" windows like tabs which are part of a single application window).

* Or "client" as it is known from the perspective of X as opposed to the user.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have it backwards? `Mod4-Shift-c` should kill the current client. Closing a sub-window is application-dependent, the WM doesn't have anything to do with that

Comment: Well, it works. For example, if you go into the Firefox preferences window and press it, it closes the preferences and not the application. Same with the search box in jEdit. So I think "Kill focused client" as it says in `man awesome` is misleading.

Comment: `Mod4-Shift-c` will close the currently focused window.  If that is the last window of the application, it will close the application. The man page is correct.

Comment: @Sardathrion If you equate "client" with "window", yes. I guess that's WM developer parlance.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the answer to clarify the concepts.

Comment: I confirm that Mod4(win key) + Shift + c will close pop ups in Firefox for instance, you keep the focus in the object you want to close, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following to my clientbuttons table:

```
awful.button({ }, 2, function (c) c:kill() end)
```

Now my scroll wheel click closes the window.